# Removing all line breaks that are NOT inside th or td

Tags: php, regex

I'm making a plugin that will create a table based on some pre-existing data.

Sometimes, some of that data has line breaks (\n or \r) in the middle, and that is out of my control. After I finish parsing the data, the software will replace all line breaks with `<br>`, so I need to remove all of them that are not inside `<th>` or `<td>`

This regex will match all of them ([Fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/bO8iZ0/1)):

```
(>[^<]*)\n([^<]*<)
```

How can I make it match all line breaks, except the ones inside `<td></td>` and `<th></th>`

Thank you

Comment: How about using a DOM parser ?

Comment: @adeneo: I think it would be a bit overkill

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex.

Comment: Do you want to instead convert them to HTML line break?   If so you can use nl2br http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Why not just only run the `nl2br` on the `th` and `td`s?

Comment: @chris85  All line breaks get converted to <br> automatically. My problem are the line breaks NOT inside <td> or <th>, I want to remove them

Comment: @JayBlanchard There are exceptions to that rule. I'm not parsing a full blown HTML page,

Comment: There are exceptions but regex and HTML do not mix well, typically because HTML is badly used.

Comment: Or CSS `white-space`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex and then replace the matched `\n` chars with an empty string.

```
<(th|td)>.*?<\/\1>(*SKIP)(*F)|\n
```

`<(th|td)>.*?<\/\1>` matches all the `td` or `th` tags. Now the following `(*SKIP)(*F)` makes the match to fail and then it tries to match the characters according to the pattern which exists next to the alternation operator from the remaining string. So it matches all the new line chars which are present outside the `td` and `th` tags.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bO8iZ0/2)

**Example:**

```
$string = <<<EOT
<table>
<tr><th>HEader 1</th><th> header 
2</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>cell 
content</td><td>cell 2</td></tr>
</table>
EOT;
echo preg_replace('~<(th|td)>.*?<\/\1>(*SKIP)(*F)|\n~s', '', $string);
```

**Output:**

```
<table><tr><th>HEader 1</th><th> header 
2</th></tr><tr><td>cell 
content</td><td>cell 2</td></tr></table>
```

Reference:

- [How do (*SKIP) or (*F) work on regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way (in case there are no tags in between the `th` and `td` tags):

```
\n(?!.*?<\/(?:th|td)>)
```

In case there are tags in between, you can use Avinash's approach, or this one that also uses `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` trick, but allows any number of attributes:

```
(?s)<(t[hd])[^>]*?>.*?<\/\1>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\n
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bO8iZ0/6).

With input as

```
<table>
<tr><th>HEader 1</th><th> header 
2</th>
</tr>
<tr><td width="100"><b>cell 
content</b></td><td>cell 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Output is

```
<table><tr><th>HEader 1</th><th> header 
2</th></tr><tr><td width="100"><b>cell 
content</b></td><td>cell 2</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: @Cornwell: What about the cases when a `<td>` or `<th>` has an attribute? Have a look at my update.